# How do 99 chevy tracker rear brakes self adjust?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, tracker

I adjusted the brake shoes a bit after I installed them, but do they now adjust on their own as they are used or how do I get them to adjust?

Answer (score 1):

When you operate the parking/e-brake its cable pulls a lever in the brake shoe assembly which rotates the star wheel adjuster to take up any free play inside of the drum. It incorperates a bi-metal strip which prevents adjustment of the shoes when the brakes are hot. If this is not working the brakes will jam on when the brakes cool, because of expansion an contraction due to the heating and cooling of the brakes. The cable has an adjuster outside and seperate to the brake drum assemblies to adjust the length of the cable. The cable is a manual adjustment, the inside-drum adjuster is automatic, but will benefit from your initial adjustment.